# Electron-Typescript: Bundling everything

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, electron

I'm trying to create a web app using electron written in Typescript. I'm having problems when building my application. Specifically, I am not sure on how to combine: `tsc` (To convert my `.ts` file to `.js`) and then `electron dist/main.js`. Potentially, I want to run `npm start` which first compiles my `.ts` file and then run electron. Can anyone comment on what would be the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ts-loader](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader) with webpack to bundle `.ts` files with config like below,

```
const path = require("path")
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

and then in your npm script include these,

```
{
    "build-watch": "webpack -w",
    "electron": "electon dist/main.js"
}
```

then start both using [npm-run-all](https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all) (or any other tool like [concurrently](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/concurrently)),

```
npm-run-all start build-watch electron
```

Comment: @MayankAggarwal  you have to import it in your code, i have updated the code.

Comment: @MayankAggarwal you'll have to also change `entry` and `output` fields according to your needs.

Comment: Made necessary changes but `webpack -w` seems to be failing. I am getting few errors/warnings including `Insufficient number of arguments or no entry found.` and `ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'main.ts' in '/Users/mayankaggarwal/Desktop/MailApp'`. My entry looks like: `entry: 'main.ts'` which exists in root folder.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using https://webpack.electron.build/. It has instructions for adding typescript support here https://webpack.electron.build/add-ons#typescript